# What is the huge Downloads file in my systems root directory and can it be shrunk or deleted/

Tags: root, downloads, system

I have a 43.0 GB file called Downloads in my systems root directory. It is not my Downloads folder in my user directory. It seems kind of big and I am wondering if I can make it smaller or at least understand what it is. Is it like a temp folder or log of everything I download? And if so, should I be cleaning it every so often or something? I have been a Linux user for a little while now, but am not an expert by any means and am still learning. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 if that helps or matters. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l6t4.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpKWR.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFeNA.png)

Comment: That isn’t normal. I’d be inclined to delete it. If you want to be super careful check the date it was last modified and check it again in a week. Alternatively move it and see if anything is broken again after a week. I’m 99.9% sure it can be safely deleted.

Comment: @PonJar Please don't answer in comments.  If you have an answer, write it as an *answer*.

Comment: be careful. Is it a file or a dir? That could be a mounted volume name /Downloads/

Comment: It is not a folder or directory, it is a file (no file extension) and when I check the properties, it shows that it is owned by root and the type is Binary (application/octet-stream).

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1420693/edit) to show us actual input and output instead of *describing* the output in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stock install of Ubuntu does not create a `/Downloads` directory, so it's safe to remove without damaging your system.

HOWEVER, you should review the contents of that directory first to ensure there is not data in there that you wish to retain.

Also review `/etc/fstab` to make sure that you didn't create that location as a mount point for some external (or internal) stoarge device.

The most likely reason for creation of a `/Downloads` directory is a user mistake. For example, a typo: It's a single character away from `~/Downloads`, so a typo in a shell command is certainly a possible cause.

Comment: It is not a folder or directory, it is a file (no file extension) and when I check the properties,  it shows that it is owned by root and the type is Binary (application/octet-stream).

Comment: I would save your personal data and install new. But I am paranoid.

Comment: @PastorMichael By any chance, did you try to copy something big to your Downloads directory (the "real" one, within your home folder) and mistyped the name, so it became `/Downloads` instead of `~/Downloads`? In that case, if `/Downloads` folder did not exist previously, so the copied data has been placed in the root directory and formed a file named `Downloads` (however, you must have done it with root privileges, as otherwise it should not be possible to create a file in root directory).

Comment: No, I have not moved any files via the CLI into my Downloads folder. I never use root privileges unless absolutely necessary to fix an issue. I edited my question to include some images that may or may not help as requested.

Comment: The original answer stands: "*it's safe to remove without damaging your system*"

Comment: Oh did add it under answer not under question.